# How to change the same characters in a string to different values in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a basic converting program, changing stars to either `<em>` or `</em>` depending on if they are the first or second of a pair, but regardless of what I do my program changes all the stars to `<em>` or `</em>`.

```
line = "*ju*bil*ee*"
star_counter = 0
new_line = line
    for character in line:
         if character is "*":
            star_counter += 1
            if star_counter%2 == 0:
                new_line = line.replace(character, "</em>")
            else:
                new_line = line.replace(character, "<em>")
```

Comment: look up the definition of string.replace in python. problem solved: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm. U need to limit the number of changes to 1 else ALL will be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

You're already looping over the input string character by character, so just append to the output (your toggling of opening/closing `em` tags is ok).

```
line = "*ju*bil*ee*"
expected = "<em>ju</em>bil<em>ee</em>"
star_counter = 0
new_line = ""
for character in line:
  if character is "*":
    star_counter += 1
    if star_counter%2 == 0:
      new_line += "</em>"
    else:
      new_line += "<em>"
  else:
    new_line += character

assert new_line == expected
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the assert does, but the rest of the syntax works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: [assert](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively) ensures that an expression is true - otherwise it will throw an exception (makes it useful to "prove" in an easy way that a code snippet like above is correct)

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `cycle` and `imap` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import cycle, imap

em = iter(cycle(['<em>','</em>']))

def emEm(c):
    if c == '*':
        return em.next() 
    else:
       return c

line = imap(emEm,"*ju*bil*ee*") 
print(''.join(line))
```

- `cycle(['<em>','</em>'])` lazyly repeats `<em>` and `</em>` as often as needed
- `emEm` implements the decider logic for imap
- `imap` executes the logic on each character of the string

Problem: with odd number of * you get a not well formed html - tag opens but does not close - but you could check that beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_line = "*ju*bil*ee*"
star_counter = 0
for character in new_line:
    if character is "*":
        if star_counter == 0:
            new_line = new_line.replace(character, "<em>", 1)
            star_counter=1
        else:
            new_line = new_line.replace(character, "</em>", 1)
            star_counter = 0
print(new_line)
```

Output

```
<em>ju</em>bil<em>ee</em>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regular expression substitution.

```
import re
new_line = re.sub(r'\*([^*]+)\*', r'<em>\1</em>', line)
```

The regular expression matches two `*` with some non-`*` characters between them, uses a capture group to capture the in-between text, and then substitutes that capture group between `<em>` and `</em>` in the result.